# Unable to use intent in adapter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, adapter

While firing `Intent` `finish` activity i am getting this error

```
03-20 11:05:16.991 8566-8566/com.example.jenya1.ebilling E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.jenya1.ebilling, PID: 8566
                                                                       java.lang.ClassCastException: droidninja.filepicker.FilePickerDelegate cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
                                                                           at com.example.jenya1.ebilling.adapter.MaterialAdapter$1$1.onClick(MaterialAdapter.java:142)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

This line causing error

```
((Activity)mContext).finish();    //error
```

calling apapter class

```
private void loadMaterialRequest() {

    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    //getting the progressbar

    //making the progressbar visible
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    albumList.clear();

    //creating a string request to send request to the url
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, HttpUrl+token+"&type="+type,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //hiding the progressbar after completion
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    try {
                        //getting the whole json object from the response
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                        JSONArray heroArray = obj.getJSONArray("response");

                        //now looping through all the elements of the json array
                        for (int i = 0; i < heroArray.length(); i++) {
                            //getting the json object of the particular index inside the array
                            JSONObject heroObject = heroArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            //creating a hero object and giving them the values from json object
                            Material hero = new Material(
                                    heroObject.getInt("Request_id"),
                                    heroObject.getString("Site_name"),
                                    heroObject.getString("User_id"),
                                    heroObject.getString("Item_name"),
                                    heroObject.getString("Quantity"),
                                    heroObject.getString("Country"),
                                    heroObject.getString("Request_date"),
                                    heroObject.getString("Request_status"));

                            //adding the hero to herolist
                            albumList.add(hero);
                        }
                        //Log.e("list", String.valueOf(albumList));
                        //creating custom adapter object
                        adapter = new MaterialAdapter(getApplicationContext(),albumList);

                        //adding the adapter to listview
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    Log.e("error", String.valueOf(error));

                }
            });

    //creating a request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //adding the string request to request queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

I am trying to `Intent` when user click on alert dialog yes button

This is my adapter class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.jenya1.ebilling.MaterialHistoryActivity;
import com.example.jenya1.ebilling.R;
import com.example.jenya1.ebilling.model.HistoryQuotation;
import com.example.jenya1.ebilling.model.Material;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Mitesh Makwana on 18/03/18.
 */
public class MaterialAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MaterialAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Material> albumList;
    private List lstfavquoteid;


    String quote_id;
    ArrayList<Integer> arryfavquoteid;

    Typeface tf;
    ArrayList<String> imageserver,imageList;
    int count;

    int status=0;
    private int mExpandedPosition=-1;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title,quantity,site,date,note,req_id,status;

    ImageView delete;
    LinearLayout lndetail,lnapprove,lnreject,lnoperation;
    CardView cdview;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txttitle);
        req_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtreqid);
        quantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtquantity);
        date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtdate);
        site = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtsite);
        note = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtnotes);
        status = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtstatus);

        delete=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgmdelete);

        lndetail = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.lndetails);
        lnapprove = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.lnapprove);
        lnreject = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.lnreject);
        lnoperation = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.lnstatusoperation);
        cdview = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
    }
    }

    public MaterialAdapter(Context mContext, List<Material> albumList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.albumList = albumList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.raw_material_history, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    arryfavquoteid = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    imageserver = new ArrayList<String>();

    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/HKNova-Medium.ttf");
    holder.title.setTypeface(tf);
    holder.req_id.setTypeface(tf);
    holder.quantity.setTypeface(tf);
    holder.date.setTypeface(tf);
    holder.site.setTypeface(tf);
    holder.note.setTypeface(tf);

    final Material album = albumList.get(position);

    holder.title.setText(album.getItem_name());
    holder.req_id.setText("#"+album.getId());
    holder.quantity.setText(album.getQuantity());
    holder.site.setText(album.getSite_id());

    String  input = album.getRequest_date();
    input = input.replace(" ", "\n");
    holder.date.setText(input);
    holder.note.setText("Notes : "+album.getCountry());

    holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
//                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Delete...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    view.getContext());
            alert.setTitle("Alert!!");
            alert.setMessage("Are you sure to delete record");
            alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    MaterialHistoryActivity.deleterequest(mContext,album.getId());

                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                    Intent i=new Intent(mContext,MaterialHistoryActivity.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(i);
                    ((Activity)mContext).finish();    //error

                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            alert.show();
        }
    });
    if (mExpandedPosition == position) {

        if(album.getRequest_status().equals("1"))
        {
            holder.status.setText("Approved");
            holder.status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.status.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            holder.lnoperation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else if(album.getRequest_status().equals("2"))
        {
            holder.status.setText("Rejected");
            holder.status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.status.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            holder.lnoperation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.status.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.lnoperation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        //creating an animation
        Animation slideDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.slide_down);

        //toggling visibility
        holder.lndetail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //adding sliding effect
        holder.lndetail.startAnimation(slideDown);
    }
    else
    {
        holder.lndetail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    holder.cdview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //getting the position of the item to expand it
            mExpandedPosition = position;

            //reloding the list
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });


    holder.lnapprove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
//                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Approve...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            MaterialHistoryActivity.materialpermission(mContext,album.getId(),1);
        }
    });

    holder.lnreject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
//                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Reject...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            MaterialHistoryActivity.materialpermission(mContext,album.getId(),2);

        }
    });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
    return albumList.size();
    }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: comment your error line

Comment: From Where you are calling adapter?

Comment: post the code how you are calling the adapter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let see:

```
((Activity)mContext).finish();
```

The log say mContext is kind of FilePickerDelegate. So check your Adapter init function. I think you pass context as "this", but "this" reference to  FilePickerDelegate. So change it to YourActivity.this ( with activity) or getActivity( in fragment)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the Application Context not the Activity Context in your adapter.

getApplicationContext();
Wherever you are passing it pass this or ActivityName.this instead.

Since you are trying to cast the Context you pass (Application not Activity as you thought) to an Activity with

(Activity)
you get this exception because you can't cast the Application to Activity since Application is not a sub-class of Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Context use Activity in your adapter. As Activity can be cast to context but context can not be cast to activity.

```
Activity avtivity;

public MaterialAdapter(Activity activity, List<Material> albumList) {
this.activity = activity;
this.albumList = albumList;
}
```

In your calling activity when you initialize your adapter Call this adapter like below.

```
new MaterialAdapter(<your calling activity>.this, yourList);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(mContext, MaterialHistoryActivity.class));
```